# Display rounded number in a span in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

A tool that I am using is displaying a room temperature on a smart mirror. This line of code is creating the temperature value:

```
var temperatureTextWrapper = document.createTextNode(
   zone.state.sensorDataPoints.insideTemperature.celsius + "°"
);
```

After this the `var` is just being appended to an existing `span`.
By default, the value contains two decimal places eg. `25.76°C`. However I would love to have it rounded to one decimal place or even full integers.

I already tried the `.replace()` or `.slice()` functions but with no success. What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.round()` to round to the nearest integer.

```js
var temperature = 25.76;

// Nearest integer
console.log( Math.round(temperature) )

// One decimal place
console.log( Math.round(temperature*10)/10 )
```

In your case, you could use:

```js
var temperature = zone.state.sensorDataPoints.insideTemperature.celsius;

var temperatureTextWrapper = document.createTextNode(Math.round(temperature) + "°");
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thanks a lot for your very fast help.

Comment: Notice that you miss the decimal values here

Comment: @Itamar Thanks, I've added both options to the answer now.

Comment: Math.round *10 /10? why not just parseFloat?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to this code, you can manipulate is using `toFixed` on the data itself:

```js
// If the value is a float
const to1Decimal = zone.state.sensorDataPoints.insideTemperature.celsius.toFixed(1)

// If the value is a string
const floatValue = Number.parseFloat(zone.state.sensorDataPoints.insideTemperature.celsius)
const to1Decimal = floatValue.toFixed(1)
```

If you don't you can find this element in the DOM (which will require some more information about the HTML to help you with) and then manipulate it:

```js
// Assuming we found the node
const text = elementNode.innerText
const toFixed1Place = Number.parseFloat(text.split("°")[0]).toFixed(1)
```

See MDN Page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed